# Unable to Figure out the issue with code(Keylogger in Python with win32api)

Tags: python, python-3.x, keylogger

I am following this tutorial series-[Neural Network Training Data for self-driving - Python plays GTA p.9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4y4YOpUcTQ)

This is the code which is provided on the github link which i am trying to modify-[Github Getkeys.py](https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/blob/master/getkeys.py)

Basically in this code,we are using the python win32 api in order to record keypresses.

The code is as follows-

```
import win32api as wapi
import time

keyList = ["\b"]
for char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 123456789,.'£$/\\":
    keyList.append(char)

def key_check():
    keys = []
    for key in keyList:
        if wapi.GetAsyncKeyState(ord(key)):
            keys.append(key)
return keys
```

The problem is that i am using Pycharm Community edition and i have installed pypiwin32 which does not have this method.I basically need to make this code work without using the win32 api.

This is what i have tried.

```
keylist=["\b"]
for char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 123456789,.'APS$/\\":
    keylist.append(char)
from pynput import keyboard

    def on_press(key):
    keys=[]
    for xyz in keylist:
        try:k = key.char
        except:k=key.name

         # single-char keys

        if k==ord(xyz):
            keys.append(xyz)

    return keys

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Now this method does not work properly.And i need this code to work outside the console.i.e while this script runs,it should record all keypresses.I was wondering if someone could help me out.

Comment: Low-level hooking of the keyboard through the Win32 API is usually the only reliable way to capture input, especially when technologies like DirectInput (DriectX) are involved. Is this purely to get some test data? Or do you need to emulate keystrokes also? If the former, you could throw together a .Net winforms app that performs the same function in ~10 lines of code

Comment: @Basic This is to get the key input(Test Data). I actually need to get the keystrokes and pass this onto another function/file as input.This input will be used to train my Neural Network.Can you suggest me any other methods for the same?